# Haskell `cabal` only "partially" installing package

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

Having problems installing a Haskell package called `Tidal`, using `cabal` on Ubuntu `18:04`.

https://tidalcycles.org/index.php/Userbase

I'm not a Haskell expert and have borked this stuff a couple of times before, so am trying as fresh an install as possible, using this -

https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/

I clean out as much of the Haskell- related stuff as I can -

```
justin@justin-XPS-13-9360:~$ rm -rf ~/.cabal/
justin@justin-XPS-13-9360:~$ rm -rf ~/.ghc
justin@justin-XPS-13-9360:~$ rm -rf ~/.ghcup
```

And also any Ubuntu legacy Haskell -

```
justin@justin-XPS-13-9360:~$ sudo apt-get remove ghc
```

So that -

```
justin@justin-XPS-13-9360:~$ ghci
bash: /home/justin/.ghcup/bin/ghci: No such file or directory
```

OK let's go -

```
curl https://get-ghcup.haskell.org -sSf | sh
```

Which gives me -

```
{...}
Done installing, run "ghci-8.6.5" or set up your current GHC via: ghcup set 8.6.5
Setting GHC to 8.6.5
Done
Setting GHC to 8.6.5
Done
{...}
Successfully installed cabal-install into
  /home/justin/.ghcup/bin
Detected "/home/justin/.bashrc" on your system...
If you want ghcup to automatically fix your "/home/justin/.bashrc" to include the required PATH variable
answer with YES, otherwise with NO and press ENTER.

YES
OK! /home/justin/.bashrc has been modified. Restart your terminal for the changes to take effect,
or type "source /home/justin/.ghcup/env" to apply them in your current terminal session.
```

Let's set the `PATH` and test -

```
justin@justin-XPS-13-9360:~$ source /home/justin/.ghcup/env
justin@justin-XPS-13-9360:~$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude>
```

So far so good. Now following this -

https://tidalcycles.org/index.php/Troubleshooting_a_Tidal_install

I try the following -

```
justin@justin-XPS-13-9360:~$ cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
To revert to previous state run:
    cabal v2-update 'hackage.haskell.org,2019-11-20T01:17:49Z'
```

and then -

```
justin@justin-XPS-13-9360:~$ cabal new-install tidal --lib
{...}
Starting     tidal-1.4.4 (lib)
Building     tidal-1.4.4 (lib)
Installing   tidal-1.4.4 (lib)
Completed    tidal-1.4.4 (lib)
```

Still looks OK, but this is where the problems start -

```
justin@justin-XPS-13-9360:~$ cabal info tidal
* tidal            (library)
    Synopsis:      Pattern language for improvised music
    Versions available: 0.8.2, 0.9.9, 0.9.10, 1.2.1, 1.3.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3,
                        1.4.4 (and 99 others)
    Versions installed: [ Not installed ]
```

Hmm - `Not installed` ?? And -

```
justin@justin-XPS-13-9360:~$ ghc-pkg latest tidal
ghc-pkg: cannot find package tidal
```

Doh. However, if I look in `~/.cabal` I can see that *some stuff* has been installed -

```
justin@justin-XPS-13-9360:~$ ls -l /home/justin/.cabal/store/ghc-8.6.5/
total 100
{...}
drwxr-xr-x 4 justin justin 4096 Nov 20 06:00 tidal-1.4.4-898a4af91fab9d9d757e1a84104bbd7ca568a77d48b4679a3f4addb65912423a
{...}
```

and I can even check that the library installed in `~/.cabal/store` works properly -

```
justin@justin-XPS-13-9360:~$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded package environment from /home/justin/.ghc/x86_64-linux-8.6.5/environments/default
Prelude> :script /home/justin/.cabal/store/ghc-8.6.5/tidal-1.4.4-898a4af91fab9d9d757e1a84104bbd7ca568a77d48b4679a3f4addb65912423a/share/BootTidal.hs
Listening for controls on 127.0.0.1:6010
tidal> :t d1
d1 :: Pattern ControlMap -> IO ()
tidal>
```

However I want to use `Tidal` with its emacs extension -

https://github.com/tidalcycles/Tidal/blob/master/tidal.el

which looks up the package as follows and would require `cabal info tidal` to return a correctly installed version -

```
 '(("path" . "ghc-pkg describe $(ghc-pkg latest tidal) | grep data-dir | cut -f2 -d' '")
```

Essentially the emacs extension wants the package to live here (which would make `cabal info tidal` work)

```
/home/justin/.cabal/share/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.6.5/tidal-1.4.4/BootTidal.hs
```

But `cabal` only seems to "partially" install the package here -

```
/home/justin/.cabal/store/ghc-8.6.5/tidal-1.4.4-898a4af91fab9d9d757e1a84104bbd7ca568a77d48b4679a3f4addb65912423a/share/BootTidal.hs
```

Now I could probably hack the emacs extension to point to `~/.cabal/store` rather than `~/.cabal/share`, but I would prefer this to work properly and `cabal info tidal` to return the correct version.

Can anyone enlighten me about why `cabal` is not pushing files to `~/.cabal/share` ?

TIA.

Comment: The install was performed correctly. It is broken to install Haskell packages into a global database. Unfortunately, `cabal v1-install` does just that, which is why `cabal info` checks whether packages are in that database. `cabal v2-install` does not install packages into the global database, so it isn't broken. You should (as far as possible) *never* install anything into the global database, except for the packages that ship with GHC, and so `cabal info` should *always* say "Not installed." This question is really "how do I point this Emacs extension to a `new-install`ed package?"

Comment: It's not 'broken' to install packages into a global database, if you only want to install and use a single package (or set of interoperating packages).
Also, unless you specify otherwise, `v2-install` does install packages to a global (aka default) database, doesn't it?

Comment: Anyone with a view as to which of types 1-4 here is the "correct" one ? All very confusing :-/ https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/a7wfkd/using_ghcup_to_setup_haskell_and_installing_cabal/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this as the procedure outlined above is in fact "working", it's just that the `cabal` community seems to be moving from an "old-style" installation process to a "new-style", and that the difference isn't always clear to the newcomer. Also that certain parts of certain packages (notably `tidal.el` in the `Tidal` package) haven't yet been updated to reflect the changes in `cabal` installation procedures. Thanks!